# Storing angular routes in database

Tags: angular, typescript

Like to check how can we store routes in database. e.g.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'url-of-component
    component: ABCComponent
}
```

How can we store ABCComponent into mySQL DB? or alternatively, how can I resolve the the component based on the path of the component (e.g. /component/abc.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically load routes with `resetConfig`:

```
constructor(router:Router, http:HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('/routes').subscribe(t=> {
          this.router.resetConfig(t);
    });    
}
```

Make sure to add any dynamically loaded components to the `entryComponents` of your app module:

```
entryComponents: [MyDynamicComponent,...]
```

Alternately, if you have all your routes in an array that you can retrieve from a DB, you can add them all to `entryComponents` through the `providers` array as part of your bootstrap process:

```
@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        { provide: ANALYZE_FOR_ENTRY_COMPONENTS, multi: true, useValue: routes }
    ]
})
```

Comment: Hi @pixelbits, understand the dynamically adding of routes to the router. but is it possible to store the component e.g MyDynamicComponent into DB or resolve it based on the classpath like the following:

what I meant was if i store in DB the following:
url | ComponentClass
/url-to-component | MyDynamicComponent

Comment: hi @pixelbits, as routes array requires us to specify path and component e.g. MyDynamicComponent, how can we store a component in database based on your first solution